# Drag URL into IE 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a website, where it has a textarea on which we can drag and drop URLs. When we dropped an url, it will just display the URL.

In general if we drag and drop a URL into an IE browser it will just open the Webpage of the URL.

In IE 8, for my website, if I drop URL it into textarea its showing URL in textbox, if I drop it outside textarea it is opening the URl page

But, in IE 10, eventhough I drop it into the textarea it is opening the website of the URL, instead of showing it in textarea!

Any ideas?

Basically I want to override the URL reading of IE browser when the user is dropping the text on my control!

Example:
The below code is working in IE 8 but not in IE 10. (Drag only URL)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowResults()
{
alert("hi");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Drag URL onto textbox</p>
<input id=txtDragOrigin value=""
    ondrop="ShowResults()"
>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In chrome, we could use drag and drop fine handling only "dragover" and "drop", but in IE10 we need to handle "dragenter" as well and prevent default, otherwise my "dragover" event never fired. Try it.

Comment: Any idea how to prevent default?

Comment: The event prevent default function is which what we use in javascript for that like  **e.preventDefault();** . Try this.